# Avoid HTML table overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table

I try to create an HTML table with three columns and would like to set the width of two of the columns (in this case, the first and the third) to "auto" (the width that fits their content). I'd like the third column (the middle one) to take the rest of the space.

This works great if the content of the middle column is narrower than the remaining width of the middle column, but if the content takes more width than the column than I get a table overflow.

Is there a way to achieve this even with long texts in the middle column? (Desired behavior: "cut" the text of the middle column if needed).

```html
<div style="background-color:orange; width:200px; padding: 5px">
  <table style="background-color: pink">
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:red">
        123456
      </td>
      <td style="background-color:yellow; width:100%">
        1234567890123
      </td>
      <td style="background-color:green">
        123456
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Don't think you can achieve that with tables. If you can, you should look into flex boxes

Comment: @WillardSolutions - If I add an "overflow:hidden" attrribute to the table, the table is cut in the middle of the text, I'd like the content to be cut in the middle column (fixed width), withe the last column presenting the full text.

Comment: @buhbang I tried it with flex boxes and it does not work either

Comment: Put the overflow on the `td`, not the table

Comment: @WillardSolutions - The overflow on the td tag did not work, but using overflow with float - did! See my answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there is a way to do this with a table. Here's with flex if it works out for you.

```css
.fake_table {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  background-color:orange;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
}

.col1, .col3 { flex: 1; }
.col2 { overflow: hidden; }
  
.col1 { background-color:red}
.col2 { background-color:yellow; }
.col3 { background-color:green }
```

```html
<div class="fake_table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">123456</div>
    <div class="col2">1234567890123</div>
    <div class="col3">123456</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. I also found another solution, which is shorter (see below). What do you think about it?

Comment: @TalSheffer, it will do for the question you were asking, but once you start adding more columns, it will break. Also you will need to give the row (the pink div) a css selector `div:after` and give it a `clear: both` or it might give some unwanted side-effects once you add more rows

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
The solution is combination of float & overflow, not a table:

```
<div style="background-color:orange; width:200px !important; padding: 5px">
    <div style="background-color: pink">
        <div style="background-color:red; float:left">
            123456
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:green; float:right">
            123456
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:yellow; overflow:hidden">
            1234567890123456
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you use `clear: both` after each row. otherwise, it will get messy if you have multiple rows.